# Single sign in with Linkedin keep asking authorisation for users logged with API v1

Tags: linkedin-api

Since 1st March the sign in with Linkedin on our website doesn't work anymore.
We are still on the API v1, so we upgraded to the API v2.
Everything works fine except for old users who have been previously connected with the API v1.
Each time they sign in, they are ask by Linkedin to autorize the application to access their data.
This doesn't occur with new users who never been login with the API v1.
The problem is coming from Linkedin asking each time the autorization for our app.
If the user revoke the app in linkedin in the page https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/permitted-services, everything will works fine after.

Comment: Which OAuth permission scopes are you currently requesting with the v2 APIs? Did these OAuth permission scopes change from what you had previously requested of your users with the v1 APIs?

Comment: I request r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress before with the V1 I requested r_basicprofile and r_emailaddress.
By reading the documentation I understand the r_basicprofile doesn't exist anymore (even if I can ask for it).
I understand the authorization is ask once because the scope are different but it's every time for our old users.